# is it possible to automate selenium to find xpaths?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering about this for a long time, I tried to work my way to make it possible but no matter what condition I throw in, it doesn't seem to work, I wonder if anyone have ever tried it before, any advice is appreciated

Comment: Tried using python requests?

Comment: by finding xpaths you mean like, wait until the xpath is valid?

Comment: I mean detecting it automatically so that one doesn't have to put the path manually every time before a surge

Comment: What do you mean by "detecting it automatically"? Detecting what exactly? You want to specify something like `<div>Hello World</div>` and get its xpath?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting for example if you have a lot of website forms without consistent urls, how would you find their xpaths to input form information, something like if a website has username and password and we have defined the input for username and password we throw in the information in the form, get me ?

Comment: @Shehan Wisumperuma yes but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use getpath() to get xpath from element.

Comment: @ Shehan Wisumperuma Yh but that's not my question Ik how to find the xpath but I want to automate that proceses, I even tried making a model with tensorflow to make it work but it doesn't work